# Inserting oninput to an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Is there a way to insert [ oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" ] through JQuery or Javascript to an input field?

```html
<input aria-label="Quantity" size="4" max="10" min="1" value="1" type="range" step="1">
<output>1</output>
```

Comment: [Yes, it's possible](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up an event listener for the `input` event.

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function(){
  this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input aria-label="Quantity" size="4" max="10" min="1" value="1" type="range" step="1">
<output>1</output>
```